# does not identify the id in the table

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am making the modification for the query and already add and everything but in modifying it does not work with 'id' that I put after putting the address of the modification page

this is the table

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title> TABLA </title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <center>
      <table bgcolor="#85C1E9" border="3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="1"><a href="guarda.php">Nuevo</a></th>
              <th colspan="5">Lista de usuarios</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
        <tr>

                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido</td>
                <td>Correo</td>
                <td colspan="2"><center>Operaciones</center></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            include("conexiones.php");
            $query="SELECT * FROM usuarios";
            $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
            while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

            ?>


            <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['apellido'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['correo'];?></td>
                  <td><a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; 
             ?>">Modificar</a></td>
                  <td><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ? 
             >">Eliminar</a></td>                
             </tr>

             <?php 

             }
             ?>
         </tbody>
         </table>
             </center>
             </body>

             </html>
```

here the modify page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Guardar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <form action="guardar.php" method="POST" name="guardar"><br><br><br>

        <?php

           $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

            include("conexiones.php");
            $query="SELECT * FROM usuarios";
            $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
            $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();

            ?>

      <input type="text" required="" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..." 
      value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>"><br><br>
      <input type="text" required="" name="apellido" 
      placeholder="Apellido..." value="<?php echo $row['apellido'];?>"> 
      <br><br>
       <input type="text" required="" name="correo" 
       placeholder="Correo..." value="<?php echo $row['correo'];?>"><br> 
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">


      </form>
      </center>
      </body>
      </html>
```

the error is that when I press modify in the query I get like this:

```
      http://localhost/modificar.php?id=%3C?echo%20$row[%27id%27];?%3E
```

and the way it should go (for example) is like this:

```
      http://localhost/modificar.php?id=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include("conexiones.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado=$conexion->query($query);
?>
<?php while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()): ?>


            <tr>
                  <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['nombre'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['apellido'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['correo'] ?></td>
                  <td><a href="modificar.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                      Modificar</a></td>
                  <td><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>"> 
                      Eliminar</a></td>                
             </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: it worked with the link thank you !! but I take the function of when it is the id that I call, I present the data called to modify. How do you think I could do that? I am new at this

Comment: @Jhon Papi Namahh Please clarify what you mean, i do not understand you.

Comment: jajajajaj sorry brother, is the translator. but thanks it really worked thanks. I wanted you to explain what you did to solve it. I AM NEW IN THIS PROGRAMMING AND I WANT TO LEARN ...

Comment: @Jhon Papi Namahh do not forget to rate my answer :)

Comment: i had this one:       <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\modificar.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />Array

Comment: @Jhon Papi Namahh post a `modificar.php` script